# nullException ao setar dados do banco como parametro

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Estou tentando trazer os dados do banco de dados com este método da minha classe DAO:

```
public List<Transacoes> listDBPF(){

    Connection con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
    ResultSet res;
    List<Transacoes> arrTrans = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        //view
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM vw_showTransacoes ORDER by data DESC";
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        //Executa a consulta
        res = stmt.executeQuery();
        //Execute o laço enquanto houver registros
        while(res.next()){

            Transacoes trans = new Transacoes();
            trans.getPessoaFisica().setNome(res.getString("nome"));
            trans.getServicos().setTipo(res.getString("tipoServico"));
            trans.getServicos().setValor(res.getDouble("valor"));
            trans.setObservacao(res.getString("observacao"));
            trans.setData(res.getString("data"));
            arrTrans.add(trans);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR:"+e.getMessage()+". O sistema detectou um erro interno, por favor contact o ADM");
    }

    return arrTrans;
}
```

Segue a Bean:

```
public class Transacoes {

    private PessoaFisica pessoaFisica;
    private PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica;
    private Servicos servicos; 
    private String observacao;
    private String data;
    public PessoaFisica getPessoaFisica() {
         return pessoaFisica;
    }
    public void setPessoaFisica(PessoaFisica pessoaFisica) {
         this.pessoaFisica = pessoaFisica;
    }
    public String getData() {
         return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
         this.data = data;
    }
    public PessoaJuridica getPessoaJuridica() {
         return pessoaJuridica;
    }
    public void setPessoaJuridica(PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica) {
        this.pessoaJuridica = pessoaJuridica;
    }
    public Servicos getServicos() {
        return servicos;
    }
    public void setServicos(Servicos servicos) {
        this.servicos = servicos;
    }
    public String getObservacao() {
        return observacao;
    }
    public void setObservacao(String observacao) {
        this.observacao = observacao;
    }
  }
```

Não sei o que estou fazendo errado

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   br.com.transacoes.TransacoesDAO.listDBPF(TransacoesDAO.java:42)   at
>   br.com.transacoes.TransacoesDAO.main(TransacoesDAO.java:89)
>   /home/raphael/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java
>   returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Onde é a linha 42 da classe TransacoesDAO?

Comment: É essa trans.getServicos().setTipo(res.getString("tipoServico"));

Comment: Todas três dão erro:
trans.getPessoaFisica().setNome(res.getString("nome"));

trans.getServicos().setTipo(res.getString("tipoServico"));

trans.getServicos().setValor(res.getDouble("valor"));

Comment: Percebeu que em momento algum você cria uma `PessoaFisica`  ou `Servicos` na classe `Transacoes`? Esta é a causa do erro.

Comment: Não, não está causando nenhum erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está tentando acessar referencias nulas de objetos das classes `PessoaFisica` e `Servicos`.

Ao fazer:

```
Transacoes trans = new Transacoes();
```

você cria um objeto de `Transacoes`, mas não dos objetos dentro dela. Há duas formas de se resolver isso. Uma delas é criando os objetos enquanto os preenche dentro do `while`:

```
while(res.next()){

    Transacoes trans = new Transacoes();
    PessoaFisica pf =  new PessoaFisica();
    Servicos svc = new Servicos();

    pf.setNome(res.getString("nome"));
    trans.setPessoaFisica(pf);

    svc.setTipo(res.getString("tipoServico"));
    svc.setValor(res.getDouble("valor"));
    trans.setServicos(svc);

    trans.setObservacao(res.getString("observacao")); trans.setData(res.getString("data"));
    arrTrans.add(trans);
}
```

Ou adicionando um construtor em `Transacoes` e criando estes objetos direto nele, ai você não precisa modificar o código do `while`:

```
public Transacoes(){

    this.pessoaFisica = new PessoaFisica();
    this.pessoaJuridica = new PessoaJuridica();
    this.servicos = new Servicos();

}
```

Comment: Tinha feito a solução de cima deu certo, já ia postar aqui. Mas vendo a do construtor achei muito melhor. Obrigado ajudou muito

Comment: @RaphaelMoraes de fato ela é mais elegante e te reduz o trabalho de toda vez que precisar trazer dados do banco ou criar um objeto Transacoes. :)